# Proper use of "proud" and "prideful"

Tags: word-usage

I have heard many people over use the word 'prideful' in sentences that tend to have a negative connotation. Many times, however, the sentence structure tends to sound awkward. Is there a set of rules maybe to use when deciding when to use 'proud' or 'prideful'... Or am I overthinking this one?

SAMPLE SENTENCE

> In many cases, these people are very prideful.

or

> In many cases, these people are very proud.

Answer (score 1):

[Prideful](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prideful) means having or showing arrogant superiority to and disdain of those one views as unworthy, as in haught or disdainful.

Pride is having a feeling that you respect yourself and deserve to be respected by other people.

Prideful is used in situations when one shows arrogance, conceit or vainglory and despises those he considers inferior.

You can also read an [article from this site](http://lifeyourway.net/on-the-difference-between-being-prideful-and-being-proud-of-who-you-are/).

Comment: So the word 'proud' then cannot be used to denote a negative type of pride? (Arrogant)

Comment: Yes it can, but with help of other words, as in "too proud."

Comment: Only when used in context to provide the negative meaning then...

Comment: Yes, but you should careful about using it if the audience is too sensitive.